# How to change base URL in a Mockito test in Rust?

Tags: rest, unit-testing, rust, mockito, webserver

I am relatively new to Rust and I am trying to write a few unit tests for my web service using Mockito.

In Mockito's [documentation](https://docs.rs/mockito/1.1.0/mockito/index.html), they have the following example:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
  #[test]
  fn test_something() {
    // Request a new server from the pool
    let mut server = mockito::Server::new();

    // Use one of these addresses to configure your client
    let host = server.host_with_port();
    let url = server.url();

    // Create a mock
    let mock = server.mock("GET", "/hello")
      .with_status(201)
      .with_header("content-type", "text/plain")
      .with_header("x-api-key", "1234")
      .with_body("world")
      .create();

    // Any calls to GET /hello beyond this line will respond with 201, the
    // `content-type: text/plain` header and the body "world".

    // You can use `Mock::assert` to verify that your mock was called
    // mock.assert();
  }
}
```

In the function I am trying to test, there are these lines that I want to mock:

```rust
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let result_response = client.post(Url::parse("https://libretranslate.org/translate").unwrap()).headers(headers).body(body)
        .send().await;
```

I cannot wrap my head around how to test my function that contains `libretranslate.org`, while tests contain `localhost:<random_port>`.

Should I use some kind of config file that specifies which base URL should be used while running tests?

I cannot find any article/thread/question online about Mockito in Rust with a complete example to have a look at, and I am struggling to use it.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the url, instead, why don't you pass it as parameter?

Comment: @cafce25 that is a workaround for sure, but I didn't want to change the implementation just for the tests. Because if then you remove tests from the equation, I end up using a parameter for nothing. Btw I use a const with the URL, I added it in the example like that, so that I won't need to add extra lines of code.

Comment: Any other solution would either need to modify the code under test or the hosts domain name resolution neither of which is a thing a test should do.

Comment: Tangent: in my experience you should always prefer making the URLs (scheme, domain, and base route) configurable. It doesn't matter how confident you are that the endpoint will never change, life will prove you wrong at some point (via changing domains, using a new provider, adding a proxy, etc.). I've had to rip out hard-coded URLs more often than I can count.